# Mount volume to eXist-db image

Tags: docker, docker-volume, exist-db

What is the best practice to add a volume (external persistent storage) to the exist-db official image?


My main goal is to mount external storage to save there new files, and the exist will update/store  them to the db and to it data file(__contents __.xml).

 Backup / Restore will be from this volume.

Currently I install the exist-db installer on Ubuntu image (adding Java etc.), and use this location (**/usr/local/eXist-db**/...) for the volume mount, and it works well:

I'm using kubernetes yaml to deploy it, and it mounted well.

```
...
 volumeMounts:
        - name: azurefile
          mountPath: /usr/local/eXist-db/Myfiles
...
```

But I prefare the exist default image, and it not Ubuntu , it JavaVM, so where the location to mount the volume?
or there is other best practice to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about exist-db versions 5.0.0 and up, mounting your local directory from `/usr/local/eXist-db/Myfiles` to the internal path `exist/data` will do what you want.

Note that you cannot simply mount a binary incompatible data directory, like one generate by exist-db version 4.x.x into a 5.x.x instance. For that you need to do a backup-restore.

Volumes just work the usual docker way, nothing special about it not being ubuntu/alpine/pick-your-base.

see the [official readme](https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/develop/exist-docker/src/main/resources-filtered/README.md) for more tips and tricks.

Comment: Can you recommend on base image that fits to eXist-db? 
(One that can be set automatically to start in startup? or can be set as service? AFAIK, most of images not really can set services..)

Comment: i m not sure i understand your comment, restart policy, and running as a service are defined as part of the docker polices. The Base image doesn't enter into the equation. As long as the base image supports java8 it works with exist, ubuntu, alpine, pick your poison

Comment: Thanks alot for you attention!!
Bet still I'll try to ask it in a new Q here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850183/run-exist-db-as-service-in-docker-container