# Run Exist-db as service in Docker container

Tags: docker, exist-db

I'm trying to build a docker image that will run the eXist-db as service.

 
So I run openjdk image container, install eXist-db as written in the headless installation documentation
 (here -> https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/advanced-installation#headless)
 using

```
java -jar exist-installer-5.3.0.jar -console
```

But new before save-commit this image, I want to configure it to run as service. In eXist-db headless installation written that you can run eXist-db as service.

In documentation written to enable it by the command : `sudo tools/wrapper/bin/exist.sh install`. 
 or to use `/etc/systemd` mechanism.

My first Q is:

1.I didn't find in the installation or eXist-db folders any **exist.sh** script. Where it need to be?

The second Q is:

2. As far as I knew, in docker images you can't use systemctl command or init.d etc. so how I supposed to run eXist-db and ensure it running after the container starts?
And last Q :)

3. there is need to run any periodic checker to see if the exist-db is alive? or if it not alive just need to restart the container?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular piece of software, but two specific comments: (1) You should run the database as a foreground process, and it will be the only thing running in its container; if it exits, the container will exit too, and you can monitor that.  (2) Never use `docker commit`!  It leads to unreproducible images, and you can't ask sites like SO for help if your reproduction recipe is "I ran some stuff and committed".  Write a Dockerfile instead, commit it to source control, and use `docker build` to produce an image.

Comment: But why the container will exit when the 'particular piece of software' exits?
OK, I see it, it related to the foreground approach! 
and another Q, I need to install this software, it needed some key clicks, like "choose what you want to install 1,2,3", I don't know how to install it automatically using the Dockerfile (the image is openjdk official image, type of linux dist for Java)

Comment: the 'wrapper' is used by eXist-db 4.x, v5.x has a different mechanism. Yet myself unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrapper script [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) that is good enough so that a classic installer script setup the systemd service descriptor. And you can run the service in the docker container with it as well. It did help me in the past to bring older software into the docker world.